The spectral sequence associated to an exact couple without chasing elements
$\def\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}}
\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}$I am trying to prove 011T to myself. It is a result involving an exact couple, its derived exact couple, the spectral sequence one obtains via its iterated derived exact couples, and the filtration
$$
0 = B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \ldots \subset B_r \subset \ldots
\subset Z_r \subset \ldots \subset Z_2 \subset Z_1 = E_1
$$
that one associates to a spectral sequence $(E_r,d_r)_{r\geq 1}$ (see paragraph before 011O in Section 011M).
If we work in the category $\mathcal{A}=R\textsf{-Mod}$ of modules over a ring $R$, then I am able to prove via a diagram chase that $B_{r+1}=g(\Ker\alpha^r)$ and $Z_{r+1}=f^{-1}(\Im\alpha^r)$. Note that in this case it suffices to show the last claim in 011T's statement for $T=R$. Thus, via the identification $E_r=Z_r/B_r$, the map $d_r:E_r\to E_r$ sends a coset $[x]\in E_r$ to $[gy]\in E_r$, where $y\in A$ is such that $\alpha^ry=fx$.
My question is: how can one do any of this over a general abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ without resorting to Mitchell's embedding theorem?

There is a general technique for diagram chasing in abelian categories using "generalized elements". Are you familiar with it? You can prove this using that technique, although the diagram chase involved is somewhat nasty.

@Thorgott I think I've read about at some point in MSE/MO. Do you have a reference?

A starting point are the references listed on this nlab page.
